# iOS: detect for Regular or Compact in Multitasking

Tags: ios, multitasking, splitview

in my app I allow the multitasking mode.
But I need to do some action if my view is too restricted.
Watching Apple documentation I saw this image

[image]

You can see that in iPad Pro in SplitView, both views are regular, instead in other iPads both views are compact.
I there something that allow me to know if my current view is regular or compact?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
if (self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular){
        NSLog(@"REGULAR HORIZONTAL");
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"COMPACT HORIZONTAL");
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: Hi CrazyDev, where do you have placet this piece of code? I noticed that  "override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)" is not called when size change in Split View.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle it programatically, you can override `-traitCollectionDidChange:` and look at the self.traitCollection property on that view and make changes depending on the output.

However `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` will get you a more fine grained response to how big the view controller has been resized to.

Comment: Hey @David I found a solution, I'm going to replay in my question